# i'm with an error or bug in the library selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have this bug/error in selenium. Could you help me figure it out? i've already reinstalled the webdriver and it goes on like this

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keU70.png)

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61264/devtools/browser/527472ae-6b78-4f06-a7bb-d740b906ec7e
[6916:6896:0514/085747.521:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(408)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, 
Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string:

[6916:6896:0514/085749.135:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.        
PS C:\Users\Brayan\Documents\pytest> [6916:6896:0514/085800.567:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.
```

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.By import By

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get(r'https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72240271/edit')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I face the same bug with c# Selenuim library